# Packages for OCR and NLP

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, stacks, packages, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any package in **ROS hydro** for optical character recognition (OCR) and natural language processing (NLP)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205195/packages-for-ocr-and-nlp/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any ROS specific OCR package. You can integrate with standard libraries. There is a speech recognition package [pocketsphinx](http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx) which is used regularly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-03-19**:
I found "cob_read_text" and "read_text" are the packages of OCR supported for electric, aren't these packages available for hydro and indigo?